# Mapping between User and UserInfo

Tags: sql, spring-data-jpa, mapping

So lets say I have one entity

```
User:  
id | username | password | role
```

Then I have two others which will represent additional information, NormalUserInfo and AdminUserInfo

```
NormalUserInfo:
id | bio | age

AdminUserInfo:
id | level | status
```

So lets say we are logged in as Admin and want to update it via JPA AdminUserInfoRepository. Is it appropriate to get the currently logged in user ID and then just create an entry in AdminUserInfo table and set the ID to the currently logged in user without creating a mapping between the two tables. If not, how should I map them?
Another way I think of doing it is when a user is created, an entry for it to be automatically created in the corresponding info table based on his role but I don't know how to do that

Comment: trying to understand your question. Are you saying Admin users should be inserted in both the tables which are NormalUserInfo and AdminUserInfo?

Comment: @django-unchained No, users are kept in the USERS table. But different types of users can have different information about them. So my question is if its ok to just save the additional information about the user in a separate folder without creating mapping between the USER table and the USERINFO table but just use the ID from the USER table and use it as primary key in the USERINFO table.